# How to send email to all user with condition using php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, email, foreach, laravel-5

I am using PHP Laravel v5.0. And I want to send email to all user where divisi = X. The query of $penerima shows 3 emails which divisi = X. But the email just sent to 1 email of 3 emails. Do you know which wrong of my code? thanks

```
if ($approve != null){
        foreach ($approve as $X) {
            $penerima = User::select('email')
                             ->where('divisi','=', $X)
                             ->where('deleted','=', '0')
                             ->get();

            Mail::send('mail', $data_nomor, function ($m) use ($penerima) {
                $m->to($penerima)->subject('Respond Reminder!');
            });
        }
    }
```

If I am showing the result of $penerima,  the result is

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => App\User Object ( [table:protected] => users [hidden:protected] => Array ( [0] => password [1] => remember_token ) [connection:protected] => [primaryKey:protected] => id [perPage:protected] => 15 [incrementing] => 1 [timestamps] => 1 [attributes:protected] => Array ( [email] => hend0@gmail.com ) [original:protected] => Array ( [email] => hend0@gmail.com ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [fillable:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [with:protected] => Array ( ) [morphClass:protected] => [exists] => 1 ) [1] => App\User Object ( [table:protected] => users [hidden:protected] => Array ( [0] => password [1] => remember_token ) [connection:protected] => [primaryKey:protected] => id [perPage:protected] => 15 [incrementing] => 1 [timestamps] => 1 [attributes:protected] => Array ( [email] => hsaput208@test.co ) [original:protected] => Array ( [email] => hsaput208@test.co ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [fillable:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [with:protected] => Array ( ) [morphClass:protected] => [exists] => 1 ) [2] => App\User Object ( [table:protected] => users [hidden:protected] => Array ( [0] => password [1] => remember_token ) [connection:protected] => [primaryKey:protected] => id [perPage:protected] => 15 [incrementing] => 1 [timestamps] => 1 [attributes:protected] => Array ( [email] => diae@test.co ) [original:protected] => Array ( [email] => diae@test.co ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [fillable:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [with:protected] => Array ( ) [morphClass:protected] => [exists] => 1 ) ) )

if I changed the get() into pluck('email'), the result is just

> hsaput208@test.co

Comment: first get all emails and then send email in `foreach` loop. Now you're getting emails from query in foreach loop and then you send mail to the first one. Also it sould be `$penerima = User::select('email')->where(...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `$penerima[0]`, you just take the first User. You should give to the `to` method an array of all the emails, like so

```
$emails = User::select('email')
    ->where('divisi','=', $X)
    ->where('deleted','=', '0')
    ->lists('email');

Mail::send('mail', $data_nomor, function ($m) use ($emails) {
    $m->to($emails)->subject('Respond Reminder!');
});
```

`pluck` will give you an array of just the given column.

Depending on your Laravel version, you should use `toArray` on your pluck result...

Comment: I already change the code like yours but doesn't work, it's still sent the email to one email only.

Comment: Update your question to reflect your changes

Comment: I've updated my question. btw if I am using pluck, the result of the query is only one email, but if I am using get the result is 3 emails. when I changed into get, I've got an error "Illegal offset type"

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using exactly?

Comment: Can you also add the result of `dd($penerima);` in your question please?

Comment: Humm, I don't think this is the result of the pluck request isn't it?

Comment: yeah sorry it was get

Comment: the pluck result is just hendras50@gmail.com

Comment: Try with `lists` instead, if it doesn't work try with `->get()->lists('email')`

Comment: I am using ->get()->lists('email'), please updated your answer. Thanks a lot mate ;)

Comment: Ok great! Did you try without `get`? Just `->lists('email');`?

Comment: I've just tried. and it works too using without get :D